# Impossible to login to my azure container registry with docker login

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I created an Azure Container Registre some days ago, and now it's impossible to login to this registry with docker login command. I always get this error message:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://XXXXXXXXX.azurecr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup XXXXXXXXX.azurecr.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52627->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Comment: Have you try to restart docker ?

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano Azure support ask me to reinstall my docker client and after it works

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano but perhaps a simple restart make this work too... I don't know...

Comment: So, you solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes after a reinstall of Docker.

Comment: Nice , sometimes the support help us

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano: you have right, I tested it today: you can quit your local Docker daemon, exit your cmd console, restart your local Docker daemon and at the end restart a new cmd console and it works !

Comment: Well ! Restart a thing is the first test that you can do

Answer (score 0):

Docker client may throw such error when it is unable to connect to the local Docker daemon properly. So, Restart/Reinstall-Docker should mostly fix that.

Comment: Yes it was also the recommandation of Azure support and after it works.